# Get all the present month and year transaction and avoid previous year transaction to display

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# application with a Chart that shows monthly transaction. but I want to display the month for the current year and does not display the past year transaction.

Here is the scenario that I want to achieve, I want to display the value of July 1 2020 in chart and do not display July 7 2019 or all transaction last year.

I attached my electric bill as for reference

```
public void LoadChart1()
    {
        con.conDB.Open();
        sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Monthname(sdate) as month, IFNULL(sum(total),0.0) as total from tblcart where status like 'Sold' GROUP BY Month(sdate)", con.conDB);
        ds = new DataSet();

        sda.Fill(ds, "Sales");
        chart2.DataSource = ds.Tables["Sales"];
        Series series1 = chart2.Series["Series1"];
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        series1.Name = "SALES";
        var chart = chart2;
        chart.Series[series1.Name].XValueMember = "month";
        chart.Series[series1.Name].YValueMembers = "total";
        chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        //chart.Series[0].LegendText = "#";

        con.conDB.Close();
    }
```

[image: mysql]
[image: Chart]
[image: Picture for reference]

Comment: IFNULL is unnecessary as there is  no SUM of NULL values to return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.  But if you only want the values within the past year, then add this to your SQL statements where clause:

```
and sdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

if you only want the values within the same calendar year (e.g. 2020) then add this:

```
and YEAR(sdate) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: What if I have transaction from Jan 2020 to June 2020 and I want to display in chart. Kindly check for reference [Link]https://imgur.com/a/vNOzAd2
`SELECT Monthname(sdate) as month, IFNULL(sum(total),0.0) as total from tblcart where status like 'Sold' GROUP BY Month(sdate) and YEAR(sdate) = YEAR(NOW())`

Comment: Sorry I don't get the point of what you want to show.  You have 2 transactions in 2020, 1st June 2020 & 1st July 2020, the SQL shows these fine.  There are no transactions in January 2020.

Comment: uhhm. but the month of June does not displaying in chart Whether in mysql database. it only shows the month of july 2020 and  july 2019.

Comment: I want to achieve like our electric bill. It shows the graph for the past month.

Comment: Actually sorry I was wrong.  You only have 1 record in 2020, 1st July.  The 1st June is actually 2018, I misread it.  If you want the same as the picture, then you need more data!  Or are you not showing us everything?

Comment: I have update my table. In current year 2020 I have data which is june 1 2020 and July 1 2020. But It only retrieve the data of month of July 2020 but where is the month of June 2020? 
2nd Question is it possible not to display the previous year of 2019 because if we are in year of 2025 it will expand my chart from year of 2019 to 2025, all datas will display that will ruin my UI :(( [update picture]https://imgur.com/6GKec7H

Comment: the Month of June was remove when i follow your syntax  `and YEAR(sdate) = YEAR(NOW())`

Comment: What exactly do you want?  Do you want all entries in current calendar year or all entries in past 12/13 months or last 13 entries by date?

Comment: I want to achieve what exactly represent from our electric bill. as you can see there is data comparison within my20 and my19(May2020,May2019) and shows the previous month like ju19 to ap20. so I have update my data to retrive the month of June etc. [link]https://imgur.com/6GKec7H

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217000/discussion-between-kennytan-and-jason-kaisersmith).